# Updating a binary file in real-time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program to read data from binary file (the binary file includes data from ADC 32 channels) and to filter them , then to split them into other files (for every channel its file). I'll show you this part of code.

This code works perfectly with already written binary files, but now I need to do the same thing but with an updating binary file, to filter and split the data in real-time while the ADC is recording.

I thought of an algorithm but I'm not sure if it's the best one:

I think, in the recording time, the code will read some chunk from the binary file and filter it and rewrote it in splited files, then will have a time.sleep(1) ( for example) and then do the same with the next chunk and so on. And in this time the results will be shown in graphic. And I'll try to find the best size the chunk to minmize the delay...

If my algorithm is right, would you please tell me how to do it? And if there another way, would you please tell me also what and how to do?

```
file,ext = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
# reading binary file
sss = int(os.stat(file).st_size/2)   
statinfo = os.stat(file)

with open(file, 'rb') as fb:
    bin_f = array.array("h")
    bin_f.fromfile(fb, sss)



res =''
Channel_number = int(str(self.lineEdit_3.text()))
for x in range(1,Channel_number + 1):    # range for 32 bit. for 8 bit the range will be (1,9)
        y = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())  # folder name
        y_2 = str(self.lineEdit.text())  # file name
        folder_path_1 = os.path.isdir(os.getcwd() + '/' + y +'/' + y+'{}'.format(x))
        if not folder_path_1:
            folder_path = os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), y + '/' + y +'{}'.format(x)))
# write the data from every channle to it's folder with txt format        
for x in range(1,Channel_number + 1):    # range for 32 bit. for 8 bit the range will be (1,9)
        y = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        folder_name = str(self.lineEdit.text())
        coef_1 = float(self.lineEdit_9.text())
        coef_2 = float(self.lineEdit_10.text())
        num_spe = int(self.lineEdit_11.text())
        folder_path_1 = os.path.isdir(os.getcwd() + '/' + ' Data File' + '/' + y +'/' + y+'{}'.format(x))
        if not folder_path_1:
            folder_path = os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),' Data File' + '/' + y + '/' + y +'{}'.format(x)))...
```

Comment: any body!!!? 
:(